# Write cell value from one column to a location specified by other cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013, formulas

I have a value in Column A which I want to write to a separate sheet, there are column and row numbers which specify the location I want to write that value in the same row as the value in column A.

For instance the value in A8 has column number "2" in Q8 and row number "118" in S8. So I want to write a formula in the new sheet which puts the value of A8 into cell B118 in the new sheet. And for this to go down with all the values in A:A as the first sheet continues to be filled in.

I've tried doing this with sumifs formula here but its not quite working out;

```
=IF(SUMIFS(sheet1!$A:$A,sheet1!$Q:$Q,COLUMN(B8),sheet1!$S:$S,ROW(B8))," ",sheet1!$A:$A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the formula in the new sheet to reference the **cell** in *Sheet1* then:

```
Sub marine()
   Dim cl As Long, rw As Long, source As String

   cl = Range("Q8").Value
   rw = Range("S8").Value

   Sheets("new").Cells(rw, cl).Formula = "=Sheet1!A8"

End Sub
```

and if you simply want **A8**'s **value** transferred to the new sheet, then:

```
Sub marine2()
   Dim cl As Long, rw As Long, source As String

   cl = Range("Q8").Value
   rw = Range("S8").Value

   Sheets("new").Cells(rw, cl).Value = Range("A8").Value

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a version that will handle the entire column:

```
Sub marine3()
   Dim cl As Long, rw As Long, source As String
   Dim i As Long, N As Long

   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 8 To N
      cl = Range("Q" & i).Value
      rw = Range("S" & i).Value
      If cl <> 0 And rw <> 0 Then
         Sheets("new").Cells(rw, cl).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately I dont just need row 8 transferred, my data happens to start at 8 and then I need all the values in A:A transferred as far down as the data goes, which will grow as the sheet is filled in throughout the year. Is there a way to do this with whole column ranges so Q:Q, S:S, A:A and dynamically know the last row to stop?

Comment: @jrb2b  Do you want to extend **marine()** or **marine2()** ??

Comment: Hmm not sure, if we go with marine2 then I can just have a button which runs that sub, wiping the new sheet then transferring all the values across to where they need to go thus updating it?

Comment: @jrb2b  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks so much Gary's Student, this does the job very elegantly. I will just tweak it now to clear the preexisting cell contents when I rerun the submodule. Cheers

Comment: @jrb2b  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

```
Sub movindData()
    'take all the data from sheet1 and move it to sheet2
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim r
    Dim c
    Dim i
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim A 'for each value in column A
    Dim Q 'for each value in column Q (the column)
    Dim S 'for each value in column S (the row)


    r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'the botton of columns A, the last row
                                    'I take the inicial cells as a A1, but you
                                    'can change it as you need.
    c = 1 'the column A

    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, c)) 'this takes just the range with the data in columns A
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2") 

    For Each i In rng
        A = i.Value 'Store the value of every cell in column A
        Q = i.Offset(0, 16).Value 'Store the value of every cell in column Q (the destination column in sheet2)
        S = i.Offset(0, 18).Value 'Store the value of every cell in column s (the destination row in sheet2)
        sht2.Cells(Q, S).Value = A
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This unfortunately gives an error on the line "sht2.Cells(Q, S).Value = A", I have gone with Gary's Students answer as that has done the job for me. Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question though Elbert!